# Connection to mysql database failed while trying to run ionic project on android

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run an ionic application using nodejs as server to connect to mysql database on android , the application runs perfectly on lab but when it comes to android it failed to connect to localhost , apparently the emulator couldn't recognize the address am using .This is the code am using in my ionic service  :

````
export class CandidatService {
  base_path = 'http://10.0.2.2:1617';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Http Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }

  getAllCandidats(): Observable<Candidat[]>
  {
    return this.http
      .get<Candidat[]>(this.base_path+"/selectAllCandidats", this.httpOptions)
      .pipe()
  }
}```
````

Comment: Can you please shared errors logs ?

Comment: Your mobile application and your nodejs server should run in the same wifi, that you can connect to this IP address, or as its' mentioned in the answer you can use ngrok service to get an https URL, or the third option you need to deploy your nodejs server in a cloud provider like AWS , heroku

Answer (score 1):

is this ip and port is the valid nodejs server app?

```
http://10.0.2.2:1617
```

do you have console.log on what happen on the nodejs ? 
is your nodejs server and your android is running on `same wifi` ?

if no, then you might need to use public ip 
or the simple one is using `ngrok`

reference : https://ngrok.com/